# Difference in JVM heap size allocation between Netbeans 7.0.1 and 7.1?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, netbeans-7.1

I have a java program that I developed using Netbeans 7.0.1 to parse and save large CSV files. Because of the size of the CSV files I needed to increase the heap size of the JVM. In 7.0.1 I set the heap size to use 4GB of my 8GB on my system using the -Xmx4096m specification under Project ->Properties -> VM Options in Netbeans. It worked fine in 7.0.1.

Now I'm trying to run it in Netbeans 7.1 and I'm getting the following for output from Netbeans

```
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Java Result: 1
```

I've changed nothing from default in Netbeans when I get this error.

I figured that maybe in 7.1 they had "locked" the heap size in the netbeans.config file so I went there.

First I tried this:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Xmx4906m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

That gives me a Failed to create JVM popup at Netbeans splash screen.

Then I tried this:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

Netbeans seems to like that better as the load bar will go all the way to "Done loading modules." but then it just hangs on the splash screen. I let it hang there for 5 mins before killing it.

This isn't a show stopper for me since I can still run it fine under 7.0.1 but was wondering if anyone had a solution to this. Seems like it should be an easy fix but I'm just overlooking something?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you installed your NetBeans with a 32-bit java.exe, Edit your netbeans.conf in C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.1\etc\ or C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1\etc\
and make sure it says (replace jdk1.7.0_03 with the version you actually intend on using):

```
...
# Default location of JDK, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir>:
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03"
...
```

and not

```
...
# Default location of JDK, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir>:
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03"
...
```

note that the "(x86)" in Windows means 32-bit, or just edit your project and pick a 64-bit JVM.  You may have to add your 64-bit JVM to Tools->Java Platforms.  Of course if you aren't using Windows the specifics will be different but it will still be a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue.

This situation usually arises when someone wants to use a newer JVM but they accidently install the 32-bit version instead of the 64-bit.  Also note:  you can configure your project to run/debug in a 64-bit JVM while NetBeans itself is running in a 32-bit JVM, so you don't actually have to modify netbeans.conf to make your project capable of allocated 4GB.

In summary:

1. Make sure you have a 64-bit JDK installed
2. Make sure your 64-bit JDK is listed in your Java Platforms in NetBeans
3. Make sure Your Project->Properties->Libraries->Java Platform is set to the 64-bit JDK you want to use.

Comment: Yup, you turned me onto the solution. I had installed 7.0.1 pointing to the Java 7 jdk. In development I had reverted to JDK 6 using the project properties. I had to go check my 7.0.1 etc/netbeans.conf file to figure it out but when I installed 7.1 my brain was thinking "point to jdk 6 since that's what you've been using" so my 7.1 conf was pointing to 1.6 while my 7.0.1(working) was pointing to 1.7 even though I was using 1.6 in my projects.